# Weapon Stocks - Are higher numbers more effective?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

During weapon customisation in MGSV, one of the parts you can change are the stocks. My question is:

Do the higher numbered versions of a stock confer incrementally better benefits?

For example, does Sharpshooters Stock **3** have more of an effect than Sharpshooters Stock **1**? The stock description implies not (and I'm speculating this is the case), however I'd like to know if anyone has any concrete sources or done live testing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless it reflects in the stats, it just seems to be aesthetic. Even when the stats differ between stocks, it's pretty small and doesn't appear to be a super noticeable change anyway.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to mention that I personally don't really notice a difference with _any_ stock I use, but I figured it'd be a good question for those who want The Very Best.

Comment: @DaniloV IIRC some of the stocks give a veeery tiny grouping bonus (like a pixel or so)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the weapon that the stock is installed, it's non-noticiable due to their stats. Automatic rifles with lower grades seem to have a more steady  aim on *Sharpshooter Stock + 4x sight* combo but when it comes to rapid fire you start to lose aim's movement speed (1º  and 3º person). This is affected by higher and lower grades of the stocks.

Heavy machineguns stocks are the exact oposite. If you want a faster aim while gun' n' running and don't care about precision (or distance), they're the best option.

Beside this, same grade stocks have the same effects affecting only the visual of the gun.

**Source**: experimentation.